# Google Business API: How to get list of businesses for given categories within radius 50 mile of the given location

Tags: node.js, google-my-business-api

With Node.js, I am attempting to get a list of businesses for given categories within the radius of 50 miles of the given location.
I am thinking of Google My Business API and reading the google doc but I am not sure how and where to get them because I am new to Google API.
Is that possible? Any sample code would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

The GBP API method [googleLocations.search](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/googleLocations/search) does not support a concrete radius search like "50 miles". Providing parts of a [PostalAddress](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location.PostalAddress) or the center of your search as [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location.LatLng) might work though.

Alternatively, you could look into the Places API, which offers a [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) method.

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate more about "googleLocations.search"?
I am new to GMP and the doc is not enough for me to understand. :)

Comment: #vpriesner - the location search specifies max 10 of page size, how to get all results like using pagination?

Comment: The GBP API search method never returns more than 10 results, it's not meant for crawling but rather to get the closest results to your query. If this is key to your use case, you should look into Nearby Search instead.